# Using django-filter overriding list method in drf

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using django-filter to filter my viewsets in drf.

When I have a `ModelViewset`, works fine like example bellow:

```py
class MyExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = myqueryset
    model = ModelExample
     filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
     filterset_fields = {
         "field_example": ["exact", "icontains"],
         "another_field_example": ["exact", "range"],
     }
     serializer_class = MyExampleViewSet
```

My problem is when I override the `list` method using a `ViewSet`, like this:

```py
class MyExampleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, queryset=queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        return something
```

In this case my filters does not working. Is there a way of using django-filter in this case (overriding list)?

I know what I can do with query_params, but I would like to use django-filter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should take a look at how the `list` method is implemented:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Django-filter is applied at this point `queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())`.

So if you want to override the list method but keep the the filtering feature, then make sure to call `self.filter_queryset()` with the queryset.